# com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaJSExecutor$ProxyExecutorException

Tags: java, android, react-native

I face this crash on Android and I have no idea why this happens, seem like core issue of RN:

```
Caused by com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaJSExecutor$ProxyExecutorException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
      at com.facebook.react.devsupport.WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.loadApplicationScript(WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.java:167)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to my issue? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide environment info ? React Native app will crash in debug mode when WebSocket crashed.

Comment: What version of RN are you using?